# How to download the contents of a web page on to a .txt file using wget in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, cmd, command-line-interface

The page that I'm trying to download from (made up contact info):

```
http://www.filltext.com/?rows=1000&nro={index}&etunimi={firstName}&sukunimi={lastName}&email={email}&puhelinnumero={phone}&pituus={numberRange|150,200}&syntymaaika={date|10-01-1950,30-12-1999}&postinumero={zip}&kaupunki={city}&maa={country}&pretty=true
```

The command that I have been using (I have tried a lot of different options etc.):

```
wget -r -O -F [filename] URL
```

It works in the sense that it downloads the web page content to the file, but instead of being the raw data that is inside the cells, it's just a bunch of curly brackets.

[image: Curly brackets instead of contact info]

How do I download the actual raw data instead of the JSON file? Any help would be very much apppreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like `wget google.com -q -O -` ?

Comment: I got it working. I think it was because of some special characters in the URL that it didn't do what I wanted it to do. I just added quotes to the url and used -r and -O options. Thanks!